# How to import external JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, import

This will be my second HTML/CSS and Javascript project so I am very much a beginner. I am trying to allow the user to draw some shapes/lines on a canvas, and then use an external library called *curve-matcher* to compare a predetermined shape with the user-drawn shape.

I began with creating a canvas where the user can draw, in an HTML file named index.html . I have 1 button that clears the canvas, and another button that will call the external function and then display the similarity score. This works fine, with code below.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false, prevX = 0, currX = 0, prevY = 0, currY = 0, dot_flag = false, coordinates = [];

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#fffcf5";
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        coordinates.push({x:prevX, y: prevY});
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        alert(coordinates);
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
        coordinates = [];
        alert(coordinates);
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    function similarity(){
        alert('stop');
        // const rectangle = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 2}]
        // const cuphandle = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 1}, {x: 6, y: 1}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 3}, {x: 9, y: 6}]
        // const similarity = shapeSimilarity(rectangle, cuphandle);
        // alert
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="600" height="600" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clr" onclick="erase()">
        <input type="button" value="similarity" id="fn" onclick="similarity()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I tested the *curve-matcher* library in another file, called *help.js*. In here I essentially ran a test trial to see if the external function works as intended.

```
import { shapeSimilarity } from 'curve-matcher';
const rectangle = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 2}]
const cuphandle = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 1}, {x: 6, y: 1}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 3}, {x: 9, y: 6}]
const similarity = shapeSimilarity(rectangle, cuphandle);
console.log(similarity);
```

But when I try to put all the Javascript from the HTML file into help.js, not only does the canvas not draw but also the similarity() function does not work as intended. This is how I 'changed' my files, but essentially just copy and paste from the HTML file to the JavaScript file. Code is below.

**index.html file**:

```
<html>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="600" height="600" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clr" onclick="erase()">
        <input type="button" value="Similarity" id="fn" onclick="similarity()">
    </body>
</html>
```

**help.js file**:

```
import { shapeSimilarity } from 'curve-matcher';
var canvas, ctx, flag = false, prevX = 0, currX = 0, prevY = 0, currY = 0, dot_flag = false, coordinates = [];
const init = () => {
    alert('does not initiate');
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#fffcf5";
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

const draw = () => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    coordinates.push({x:prevX, y: prevY});
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

const erase = () => {
    alert("??")
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
    coordinates = [];
    alert(coordinates);
}

const findxy = (res, e) => {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}

const similarity = () => {
    alert('hi');
    const rectangle = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 4, y: 2}]
    const cuphandle = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 1}, {x: 6, y: 1}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 3}, {x: 9, y: 6}]
    const similarity = shapeSimilarity(rectangle, cuphandle);
}
```

Any ideas on how to get these two files to work as they do individually, but together?

Comment: Inside the `init` function you are redefining `canvas` and `ctx`. This means that they won't be available outside of the scope of `init`.

Comment: Good catch, I did not see that! However even as I remove the declarations of those variables inside init and leave declarations outside, it still does not display.

Comment: Is your script included in your HTML and does the script tag have a `type="module"` attribute?

Comment: Yes, I followed what @bluejayke said and added `<script type="module" src="help.js"></script>` right below `<body onload="init()">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why nothing is working us because the body has the function "init" called in onload, but that function is only defined in your help.js file, which was never referenced in the main html file, so it's causing an error, even if you had other scripts in the html it may cause problems, but especially now that all the JavaScript is in the other file

Basically just add a script reference

```
<html>
    <body onload="init()">
         <script type="module" src="help.js"></script>
        <canvas id="can" width="600" height="600" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clr" onclick="erase()">
        <input type="button" value="Similarity" id="fn" onclick="similarity()">
    </body>
</html>
```

But also in the help.js function itself make sure that the function "shapeSimilarity" existed in "curve-matcher", and secondly make sure curve-matcher is even a .jsm file in the same directory as your others as well, you may need to download it from the internet first before importing, check your console by pressing F12 in the browser to see if there are any import errors

Comment: I followed as you said, and it still is not drawing anything on the canvas. Also, how do I check if _shapeSimilarity()_ exists in _curve-matcher_? I thought the `import { shapeSimilarity } from 'curve-matcher'` line at the start of help.js is enough to verify that this function exists? The curve-matcher library is filled with .js.map files, is that what .jsm stands for? They are in a different directory than my HTML and .js files, they are in a node_modules folder.

Comment: @beepbeepboop ok nodes_module is usually meant for server side modules to go with node js, if you want to use them in a browser you have to compile then usually, using tools like browserfy. In guessing you saw someone use require ("curve-matcher") and then thought you do the same with import, an I wrong? Fire did you download the nodes-modules folders, did you use npm? For now just try it without the import, then make a new .jsm file for testing, in the file  type a new function or variable then `export varName` if they is what you made, then in other file `import var name from "something.jsm"

Comment: Yes, I used npm install curve-matcher. The similarity() function I want to use has a lot of dependencies such as functions from another file in the same library. If I rewrite the similarity function in another file, and then export then import it, would it be sufficient?

Comment: @beepbeepboop ya that would be sufficient, technically you don't have to export and import you can just make a new file and include all of it if you want, but ya whatever you actually export, you can import from that particular file (usually ending in .jsm or .js), but not the module babe that shows up in package.json, in general that is only for nodejs, or you can use browserfy to do it automatically

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\javie\Documents\Recognizer\help.js"></script>` allows for the canvas to be drawn, but the similarity function() is impacted and does not work when I try to import. So it feels like I am forced to choose between type='text/javascript' or type='module'?

Comment: @beep yes if you use import use module type, but import isn't going to work with npm packages anyway so you don't really need it

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<script type="text/javascript" src="help.js"></script>` above your existing script tag

Now all the methods in **help.js** will be available. This isn't generally recommended and you should read about es6 exports and the module pattern.

Comment: Adding this allows me to draw but it doesn't allow me to use the similarity() functions in the library as the import statement at the top causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scorce your help.js file in your html using a script tag with a src attribute like this `<script src="help.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

To use an external file from another website you can use this
`<script src="https://example.com/help.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I have been doing it like this forever and I have not come across any other ways that I think are more simple.

Comment: This doesn't allow import statements for my external library

Comment: As in the similarity() function does not work since the import statement I have in the beginning causes an error.